# submitting posts on pastie, or pastebin in C#

Tags: c#, http, post, pastie

I'm looking for a way to submit a post to pastie.org, or pastebin.com from within my C# app, i know ill have to use some sort of http post but im looking for specific examples..

Comment: @George, ive tried using some http poster class's, but none of them seem to work, or im using them wrong. / sending the data incorrectly

Answer (score 6):

I just wrote a simple [PasteBin client in C#](https://pastebin.com/ZpARSMNv).

You can use it as follows:

```
        string apiKey = "<your api key>";
        var client = new PasteBinClient(apiKey);

        // Optional; will publish as a guest if not logged in
        client.Login(userName, password);

        var entry = new PasteBinEntry
            {
                Title = "PasteBin client test",
                Text = "Console.WriteLine(\"Hello PasteBin\");",
                Expiration = PasteBinExpiration.OneDay,
                Private = true,
                Format = "csharp"
            };

        string pasteUrl = client.Paste(entry);
        Console.WriteLine("Your paste is published at this URL: " + pasteUrl);
```

You can obtain your API key on [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20200723043013/https://pastebin.com/api) (you need to be logged in).

Comment: Well apparently I'm going to be the first one using your code in 5 years. Upvoted! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth your while to check and monitor the HTTP GET/POST's when using your browser to post sample code/text and intercept the data and find out..Use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [HTTPWatch](http://ads.stackoverflow.com/a.aspx?Task=Click&ZoneID=4&CampaignID=177&AdvertiserID=33&BannerID=196&SiteID=1&RandomNumber=1972153845&Keywords=c%23%2cpastie%2chttp%2cpost%2cx-user-registered). This should give you an idea on what is expected in the HTTP's POST. You would need to set the content-length in the HTTP header to the actual length of the code being submitted, have a look [here](http://en.csharp-online.net/HTTP_Post) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210123193021/http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2006/04/21/76044.aspx) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient).

Wishing you a happy and peaceful 2010.
Hope this helps,